# Using AutoFixture with Moq?

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture, automoq

Using this structure.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsAdministrator()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to combine `AutoFixture` and `Moq` to accomplish the following?

1. Ensure `User.FirstName` is auto-generated
2. Ensure `User.LastName` is always "Smith" (literal)
3. Ensure `User.MiddleName` is not populated (default)
4. Ensure User.IsAdministrator() returns `True`
5. Verify `IsAdministrator()` was called.

I know this seems so simple. Here's what I tried using `AutoMoq`.

```
var config = new AutoMoqCustomization() 
{ 
    ConfigureMembers = true 
};

var fixture = new AutoFixture.Fixture();
fixture.Customize(config);

fixture.Freeze<Mock<User>>()
    .Setup(x => x.IsAdministrator())
    .Returns(true);

var model = fixture.Build<User>()
    .With(x => x.LastName, "Smith")
    .Without(x => x.MiddleName)
    .Create();
```

But that is clearly wrong. :( I am sure the syntax is simple. Thank you for any help.

`My goal`: create an object with BOTH filled properties and mocked methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following achieves the requested goals

```
public void AutoFixture_Should_Fill_Poperties_And_Mock_Methods() {
    //Arrange
    AutoMoqCustomization config = new AutoMoqCustomization() {
        ConfigureMembers = true
    };

    IFixture fixture = new AutoFixture.Fixture().Customize(config);

    Mock<User> mock = new Mock<User>();
    mock
        .Setup(x => x.IsAdministrator())
        .Returns(true);

    User model = fixture.Build<User>()
        .FromSeed(s => mock.Object) //<-- 
        .With(x => x.LastName, "Smith")
        .Without(x => x.MiddleName)
        .Create();

    //Assert

    //Ensure User.FirstName is auto-generated
    model.FirstName.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    //Ensure User.LastName is always "Smith" (literal)
    model.LastName.Should().Be("Smith");
    //Ensure User.MiddleName is not populated (default)
    model.MiddleName.Should().BeNull();
    //Ensure User.IsAdministrator() returns True
    model.IsAdministrator().Should().BeTrue();
    //Verify IsAdministrator() was called.
    mock.Verify(_ => _.IsAdministrator());
}
```

An observation was that when using

```
Mock<User> mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<User>>();
```

if would still populate the `MiddleName` property even though it was explicitly told `Without` for the build, but worked as desired when using

```
Mock<User> mock = new Mock<User>();
```

But if you were to explicitly set the member to return `null`

```
Mock<User> mock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<User>>(); // new Mock<User>();
mock
    .Setup(x => x.IsAdministrator())
    .Returns(true);

User model = fixture.Build<User>()
    .FromSeed(s => mock.Object)
    .With(x => x.LastName, "Smith")
    .With(x => x.MiddleName, (string)null) //<--
    .Create();
```

It worked.

Here is another variation of the test with a subject class that depends on the model to be injected.

```
[Test]
public void AutoFixture_Should_Fill_Poperties_And_Mock_Methods() {
    //Arrange
    AutoMoqCustomization config = new AutoMoqCustomization() {
        ConfigureMembers = true
    };

    IFixture fixture = new AutoFixture.Fixture().Customize(config);

    Mock<User> mock = new Mock<User>();
    mock
        .Setup(x => x.IsAdministrator())
        .Returns(true);

    User model = fixture.Freeze<User>(c => c
        .FromSeed(s => mock.Object)
        .With(x => x.LastName, "Smith")
        .With(x => x.MiddleName, (string)null)
    );

    //Act
    Subject subject = fixture.Create<Subject>();
    bool actual = subject.Act();

    //Assert

    //Ensure User.FirstName is auto-generated
    model.FirstName.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    //Ensure User.LastName is always "Smith" (literal)
    model.LastName.Should().Be("Smith");
    //Ensure User.MiddleName is not populated (default)
    model.MiddleName.Should().BeNull();
    //Ensure User.IsAdministrator() returns True
    actual.Should().BeTrue();
    //model.IsAdministrator().Should().BeTrue();
    //Verify IsAdministrator() was called.
    mock.Verify(_ => _.IsAdministrator());
}


public class Subject {
    private User model;

    public Subject(User model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public bool Act() => model.IsAdministrator();
}
```

Comment: Somehow I had overlooked `FromSeed()`.